# Correct format of using csv data to plot highchart

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv, highcharts

I'm trying to create  column chart using data imported from `csv` file. I have tried every possible solution on the Internet but couldn't figure out the solution to my problem.  I'm trying to show `Shop Name` on x-axis and `Sales` on y-axis.

Here is my code:

```
      <!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

        <style>
        body{
            margin-top: 30px;
            margin-left:40px;
        }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>      
        <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
                <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
                <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/PapaParse/4.3.5/papaparse.js"></script>
</head>
<body>



    </div>
    <div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $.get('stores.csv', function(csvdata) {
                    var data = Papa.parse(csvdata);
                 $('#container').highcharts({
                            chart: {
                                type: "column"
                            },
                            title: {
                                text: "Sales Analysis"
                            },
                            xAxis: {
                                ShopName: []
                            },
                            yAxis: {
                                title: {
                                    text: "Sales"
                                }
                            },
                            data: {
                                csv: data

                            },
                            plotOptions: {
                                series: {
                                    marker: {
                                        enabled: false
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                    });
                });
            });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

csv file(stores.csv):

```
Longitude,Latitude,ShopName,ShopAddress,Sales
73.2350874,34.1990918,Abbotaqbad  Civic Shopping Center,Mansehra Road Mandian,29719
74.3062887,31.5673136,Anarkali 1  9 - Babar Market,Anarkali,14212
74.3040372,31.5643123,Anarkali 263 - Babar Market,Anarkali,35928
74.4559979,31.5931715,Baghbanpura   239 - G T Road,Baghbanpura,49901
```

Comment: you've misspelled `function` up at the top - `$.get('stores.csv', functio(csvData)` - correct that first.

I'm not too familiar with highcharts, but it doesn't seem like anything is rendering because you're not actually adding the chart anywhere. It looks like you could be generating it, but then you need to add it to the actual html. Probably something like `$("#container").highcharts(chart)`

Comment: I have edited the code and have also tried many other methods but still it's not working. Any suggestion or links that could help?

Comment: Possible reason: https://www.highcharts.com/errors/14

Comment: Any solutions to solve it?

Comment: First of all, csv is not comma separated. Also, you are providing `data` without processing.

Comment: I have edit the code. Please let me know if I'm doing it the right way?

Comment: Your xAxis and yAxis labels are also confusing. Basically your code has several issues.

Comment: I'm taking sales on x-axis and shopName on y-axis.

Comment: How can you have `sales` in xAxis and `Shopname` in yAxis ? yAxis have numbers normally. What you want to do with longitude and latitude data and  shopAddress ?

Comment: Oh yes. I'm really sorry I meant the other way. ShopName on x-axis and Sales on y-axis. Latitude, longitude and shopAddress are for the maps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just to give you an example of how you can plot chart with Highchart while parsing .csv data. Code is simple and self explanatory.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>      


</head>
<body>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$.get('stores.csv', function(data) {

var lines = data.split('\n');
console.log(lines);
var shopNameData=[];
$.each(lines, function(lineNo, lineContent){
if(lineNo > 0)
    {
    shopNameData[lineNo-1] = lineContent.split(',')[2];
    }
});

var salesData=[];
$.each(lines, function(lineNo, lineContent){
if(lineNo > 0)
    {
    salesData[lineNo-1] = parseFloat(lineContent.substring(lineContent.lastIndexOf(",")+1) );
    }
});

console.log(shopNameData);
console.log(salesData);

Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Sales Analysis'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'put subtitle here'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: shopNameData,
        crosshair: false
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Sales (in Rupees)'
        }
    },
   tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<b>Shopname:</b> {point.x}<br/>',
        pointFormat: '<b>{series.name}:</b> {point.y}<br/>'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            pointPadding: 0.2,
            borderWidth: 0
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Sales',
        data: salesData

    } ]
});

});


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**.csv file used is:**

```
Longitude,Latitude, ShopName,ShopAddress,Sales
73.2350874,34.1990918,Abbotaqbad  Civic Shopping Center,Mansehra Road Mandian,29719
74.3062887,31.5673136,Anarkali 1  9 - Babar Market,Anarkali,14212
74.3040372,31.5643123,Anarkali 263 - Babar Market,Anarkali,35928
74.4559979,31.5931715,Baghbanpura   239 - G T Road,Baghbanpura,49901
```

**Points to be noted**

1. Note that in .csv there are no space after comma, so .csv must follow that or you have to edit the logic to form `shopNameData` and `salesData`
2. Host both .html and .csv at one place in some server. Otherwise, in Google Chrome, you will get CrossOrigin error.

Here is the snapshot of Chart if you will copy the `html` and name the .csv as `stores.csv` in same directory of html and host in some server.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much :) It helped alot.

Comment: I am updating the answer in few minutes, that is exactly what you wanted. Behold !

Comment: Is there a way to select first five rows from csv file and plot any chart? For example, in above graph instead of ploting for all those 4 shops can I just plot chart for Abbotaqbad, and Anarkali1 without deleting the data from csv file?

Comment: In the example, I just showed how we can parse .csv and then create data model. If you want to plot for only first 5 shops, you can simply stop parsing for `lineNo > 5`

Comment: Date Longitude Latitude ShopName ShopAddress Sales
1/1/2017 73.2350874 34.1990918 Abbotaqbad Civic Shopping Center, Mansehra Road Mandian 29719
1/2/2017 74.3062887 31.5673136 Anarkali 1 9 - Babar Market, Anarkali 14212
1/3/2017 74.3040372 31.5643123 Anarkali 2 63 - Babar Market, Anarkali 35928
2/1/2017 73.2350874 34.1990918 Abbotaqbad Civic Shopping Center, Mansehra Road Mandian 5615
2/2/2017 74.3062887 31.5673136 Anarkali 1 9 - Babar Market, Anarkali 14212
2/3/2017 74.3040372 31.5643123 Anarkali 2 63 - Babar Market, Anarkali 35928

Comment: Suppose using above data I want to plot chart for ShopName: Anarkali-1 which is on separate rows with different sales on separate dates. Is this possible? Or do I have to sort data with ShopNames then plot the chart?

Comment: When you have all information with you in .csv format, then everything is possible, You just need to parse properly your data.